# Images not showing up in Laravel project

Tags: javascript, html, css, laravel

I am working on the front-end part in a Laravel project,but my edited images are not displaying,I was given an image to use and it displays, but when I crop it, it doesn't show up at all. It just shows a background colour? Any help?

Comment: How will we figure out what is going on in your code, If we don't have the code? Plz, provide the complete code of the respective problem.

Comment: Give Us More Details to figure out the issue and solve it